# how should i use the jquery code to do to that ? (add attribute on Colon style tag)

Tags: jquery, css, drupal

how to add attribute on this style html tag

http://benchmarq.com.tw/qa/my_q_01.png  (my print screen image)

http://benchmarq.com.tw/  (this is my site)
and i create by drupal core 
and its slideshow don't have  attribute include in it (module is not include this function to use and)
so i want to add the function on it and use jquery to make it work
 i use the firebug to find the html id and class

## like this

total is 10 slideshow pic 
i want to add  for evey  data-iview (div)

how should i use the jquery code to do to that ?

thanks lot

Comment: What attribute are you trying to add?  If you want to add an attribute with jQuery just select the element or elements with something like `$('YOUR SELECTOR').attr('ATTRIBUTE YOU WANT TO ADD', 'THE VALUE YOU WANT TO ADD TO THE ATTRIBUTE');`

Comment: thank you for your response    but i want to add <a href=""> attr on div is that work

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following

```
<div id="x">your div</div>
<div id="y">second div</div>
```

Then for your jQuery code you could do something like the following.  Obviously this is just an example.

```
$('div').each(function(i){
    if(i===0)
        $(this).wrap($('<a></a>').attr({'href':'http://www.google.com','target':'_blank'}));
    else
        $(this).wrap($('<a></a>').attr({'href':'http://www.microsoft.com','target':'_blank'}));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dklingman/uDvJ5/

Comment: thank you for your response again!!

cause the div create from drupal theme module (name iview)   
so i can't edit the html code in wysywig  editor
but maybe i can edit from js file (i am weak on my js ability)

http://benchmarq.com.tw/      (site)
http://ypccoals.com/QA/QA.png  (the screen)
http://ypccoals.com/QA/iview.js   (slideshow   source code )


my idea  (is that right?)  like as follow  

http://ypccoals.com/QA/iview.js/my_idea.txt

and i want to make every div hyperlink by every url